# Updating image src using AJAX & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX and PHP to update an image src based on a selected radiobutton option.

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../images/computers/custom-pc1.png" id="buildimage" />

<script>
    function updateImage(caseid) {
            selectmenuID = document.getElementById(caseid);

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("buildimage").src = xhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("POST", "displayCase.php", true);
            xhttp.send("id=" + selectmenuID);
    };
</script>
```

displayCase.php:

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT link FROM cases WHERE id=?");
if(!$stmt) {
    die($link->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die($stmt->error);
}
$stmt->bind_result($image);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo $image;

?>
```

I have an issue with the php file :

> Undefined index: id

...on this line:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

I would like to update the src based on the id of the selected radiobutton. What have an I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You probably have the Ajax data type 'get' instead of 'post'

Comment: You probably want to get the value of the selected item `selectmenuID = document.getElementById(caseid).value`

Comment: @Jikiwiki Did you even look at the code? `xhttp.open("POST", ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done everything right except for a minor omission: You forgot to configure the data type of the POST data.

Just add the appropriate header after you create the `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Once you add this you will find that the error with the missing `$_POST` item is resolved in your PHP.